# Why is finitely presented algebra closed under coequalizer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $\text{FP}\mathbb{T}$ be full subcategory of $\mathbb{T}\text{-Alg(Set)}$ consisting of finitely presented $\mathbb{T}$-algebras in $\text{Set}$.

A $\mathbb{T}$-algebra $B$ is finitely presented iff there exists a coequalizer in $\mathbb{T}\text{-Alg(Set)}$, $F(m)\rightrightarrows F(n)\rightarrow$ B.

Then, I want to prove that $\text{FP}\mathbb{T}$ is closed under finite colimits, so I have tried to prove that it is closed under coequalizers.

Let $A,B$ be finitely presented, $F(m_A)\rightrightarrows F(n_A)\rightarrow A$ and $F(m_B)\rightrightarrows F(n_B)\rightarrow B$. Assume that $A\rightrightarrows B\rightarrow C$ is a coequalizer diagram. Then I have to find some $F(m_C)\rightrightarrows F(n_C)\rightarrow C$ but I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about how you would prove this fact for a concrete example such as groups. First show that when computing this coequalizer you can replace $A$ with $F(n_A)$. Next use the fact that free objects are projective to lift the maps $F(n_A) \to B$ to maps $F(n_A) \to F(n_B)$.